# Interesection of finitely many P-Primary ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I'm proving that the intersection of finitely many P-Primary ideals is P-Primary, but as far as I know I haven't actually used the property that it's a finite intersection anywhere.

My definition for an ideal Q being P-Primary is if it's radical is equal to P, and if $xy\in Q$ then $x\in Q$ or $y^n\in Q$ for some $n>0$. 
I'll copy and paste what I've written so far:

"We are to prove that the intersection of finitely many $P$-primary ideals is $P$-primary.

Let $\{Q_i\}_{i\in I}$ where $I=\{1,\dots ,n\}$ be a set of $P$-primary ideals i.e. $\text{Rad}(Q_i)=P$ for all $i \in I$. Also let $X=\mathop{\bigcap}\limits_{i\in I}Q_i$. If $z^m\in Q_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in I$, $m>0$, then $z\in \text{Rad}(Q_{\alpha})\Rightarrow z\in \text{Rad}(Q_i)$ for all $i\in I$. That is, if there is a power of $x$ in one of the primary ideals, then there is a power of $x$ in all of them. Suppose $xy\in X$. Then for all $i\in I$,  $xy\in Q_i$. Since the $Q_i$'s are primary, either $x\in Q_i$ or $y^m \in Q_i$ for some $m>0$. If $x$ is not in $Q_i$ for at least one $i\in I$, then there exists an $i_0$ such that $y^m\in Q_{i_0}$ for some $m>0$. By the equality of the radicals, some power of $y$ is in $Q_i$ for every $i\in I$."

I'm trying to see what would go wrong if the index set was infinite, but I'm not getting anywhere. Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 2):

> *That is, if there is a power of x in one of the primary ideals, then there is a power of x in all of them.*

Right! A *single* power of $x$ that works for all the ideals, namely the highest one that appears among all the finitely many chosen powers of $x$.

> *By the equality of the radicals, some power of y is in $Q_i$ for every $i\in I$.*

Here's where finiteness comes in. If you know each $Q_i$ contains a power of $y$, and there are only finitely many $Q_i$, you can just pick the *largest* power appearing, and that works for all of them.

In principle, this is what could go wrong: what if you had an example with ideals indexed by $\Bbb N$, and $y^i\notin Q_i$ for every $i$?  Sure, there would still be some $y^{n_i}\in Q_i$ for each $i$, but there wouldn't be a single power that worked for everything (because if $y^j$ worked for everything, it would be in $Q_j$, but wait, we said $y^j\notin Q_j$...) That is where the proof breaks down for a family of infinitely many primary ideals.

The finiteness is necessary to conclude by saying "and out of these finitely many powers of $y$, I'll just pick the largest one, and that will work for all of these (finitely many) primary ideals.

Comment: Oh I see, right that makes sense. Yeah I thought I'd finished the proof when actually I had to state that there is a power of $y$ that is in ALL the $Q_i$'s, namely the maximum, therefore it's in the intersection. Thanks a lot!